# Sharing a dynamic object between loosley coupled Modules Prism?

Tags: c#, dynamic, prism, eventaggregator

Is it possible to share an `dynamic` type object from a Module between other modules without any static referencing or `interface` or any other DI/IoC solution?

Lets say we have a GlobalEvent like this in `Core.dll` assembly:

```
public class GlobalEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<dynamic>
{
    public GlobalEvent()
    {
    }

    // public void Publish(dynamic payload) exist in base class
}
```

and in `ModuleA.dll` (has static reference to `Core.dll`), publish it like this:

```
public void RaiseVoucherAdded(Models.Voucher voucher)
{
    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<GlobalEvent>().Publish(voucher);
}

// also Voucher class is in ModuleA.dll in Models namespace
public class Voucher
{
     // members...
}
```

and in `ModuleB.dll` (has static reference to `Core.dll`), subscribe like this:

```
    this._eventAggregator.GetEvent<GlobalEvent>().Subscribe(EventOccured);
    ...
    private void EventOccured(dynamic data)
    {
        if (data.GetType().Name == "ModuleA.Models.Voucher")
        {
            DoSomethingByVoucher(data);
        }
    }
```

Well,

What are disadvantages of this solution? Is it even possible? If it is, does it support modules that created by any other CLR language in .NET?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can find answer [in this prism discussions thead](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/353930).